# R console does not show output

Tags: rstudio

The Rstudio on my mac does not show output in the console.For instance, after I run a R script, and type the name of a parameter in the console, there is no output. However, there is no such issue on a window system. What goes wrong?

Comment: Can you please provide more details?

Comment: If I type the name of a parameter in the console, I suppose that console will output the parameter. It is so for Rstudio installed on windows, but not for Mac. Is there some package that should be installed?